# Eclipse ADT Plugin: An error occurred while collecting items to be installed

Tags: android, eclipse

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=SDKProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/plugins/com.android.ide.eclipse.adt_18.0.0.v201203301601-306762.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/features/com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms_18.0.0.v201203301601-306762.jar.
Read timed out
```

How to solve this error in eclipse?
I am using Eclipse Version: 3.7.2
Please tell me how to overcome this issue?

Comment: Well, this is a good example for a bad question. How about asking something?

Comment: if your eclipse is 3.5 you can do it. download 3.6 or 3.7 then update your ADT.

Comment: I solve it. yes Me to I have same problem. changing it from http:// to https:// solved it for me.

Answer (score 10):

It says on the Google site:

> If you have trouble acquiring the plugin, try using 'http' in the Location URL, instead of 'https' (https is preferred for security reasons).

Indeed, changing it from `https://...` to `http://...` solved it for me.

Comment: Solved the problem for me but i had to do it the other way arround.

Comment: The opposite is also true :  I had trouble with http, changing in https solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Google provides the ADT-18.0.0.zip file for download directly from their website.
http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#troubleshooting

Once downloaded, then load it as a archive instead of using the URL provided on the same page.

Comment: Yeah Thanks for that. Actually I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error. I changed https to http and this time installation was successful.